# is it possible to create new worksheet in Excel 2013 using Office.js in Office Apps ??

Tags: office365, excel-2013, office365-apps, apps-for-office

I am developing task pane Office Apps in excel 2013. As part it , I have to create a new worksheet in Excel 2013 using Office.js .

Do we have any new sheet creating utility/function in Office.JS for Excel 2013 ????  or any alternate solution readily available for this ??

Please respond to my post asap as this impacts our current development.

Regards,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no such kind of feature in current Office JavaScript API. But you should be able to post a feature request to Office Development Platform User voice.

http://officespdev.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

No, I've not found a way of doing this, but my work around has been to start with a template Excel file with plenty of sheets already in it.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2016 you can use the add method in the WorksheetCollection object.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var wSheetName = 'Sample Name';
    var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(wSheetName);
    worksheet.load('name');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(worksheet.name);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
});
```

Source: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetcollection